# Tracking and reporting in sharepoint 2010 ? user accessing what kind of data ?

Tags: 2010, reporting-services, usage-counters

**I want to track 
How many times a particular user has accessed what document in document library?and i need to show this in a report format.
Also, i need to check what are links being accessed in the site by particular user?
Also, i need to see if he has clicked any of the external links in the site ?
How can i achieve this , need info urgent?**

Comment: i was able to achieve this functionality only through customization.The OOTB Auditing provides very little inforamtion on what resource was accessed and the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Enable auditing](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-HA102031737.aspx) in the Site Settings of your site collection and you can use the reports generated by SharePoint to track user activity.  However, that is limited to only what they access within that SharePoint site collection and would definitely not track external links.  If auditing is not enabled now, then it is also limited only to future actions.

If you need to do this historically, then you will have to parse your IIS logs and extract the information manually.  A utility like [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24659) helps this process but it does require a technical user.

As for external link access, you will need to pull that information from your firewall\proxy logs as that information would not be in either the SharePoint logs nor in the IIS logs.

If tracking and reporting at this level of detail is a persistent need, then you will need to look into a corporate solution, like [Envision](http://www.emc.com/security/rsa-envision.htm#!details).

Answer (score 0):

To add the requirement , the client asked if we are able to track from which webpart the user is navigating to other pages in the site .So finally i was able to achieve this functionality only through customization.The OOTB Auditing provides very little information on what resource was accessed and the time.The custom webpart was added to the master page and thus was able to track user and his relevant details and update the same in the Sharepoit list.The major thing which was done was each Webpart was assigned a resource id and kept into a master table .So every link in the site had a appended resource id which will tell me from where the user is landing from page to page.c