# How to get Unique visitors per page using the OOTB Web analytics in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-analytics

I have a SharePoint 2010(Enterprise version) intranet site that uses Windows authentication.
I am trying to implement 'Top 3 most visited pages' custom web part across a particular site. This should not count the repeated visits/hits made by a visitor.

In other words, How do I get Total number of unique hits for a page(unique in terms of visitors) ? Even if a user visits the next day, it should not count as a hit, because the user has already visited the page.

Site.GetUsageData() will give me the 'Total Hits' which includes repeated visits by the same visitor. I am looking for 'Total Unique Hits'. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Total visits (unique) /perpage/perday ??

Comment: Total visits (unique) /perpage - not per day, total till date

Answer (score 1):

Please check Google Analytics .

ELSE
1. I would recommend to have a custom developed webpart and add it to master page. In this way you can track the activities of the user across the site for each page.
2. Maintain a list where you add the user and page name . Write a CAML query to pull the data for top three visitors.

Hope this helps for your logic.
[Tracking and reporting in sharepoint 2010 ? user accessing what kind of data ?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30944/tracking-and-reporting-in-sharepoint-2010-user-accessing-what-kind-of-data)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Microsoft didn't make APIs available that would provide this data.  So, without using unsupported methods (i.e. querying the database directly) you wouldn't have a way to do this.

You could try third-party analytics packages that allow you do query their data via JavaScript and display that on the page.