# SharePoint 2010 Usage - Get Unique Visitors of a site

Tags: sharepoint-addin, web-analytics, site-usage

I am running into a requirement wherein the login IDs of the unique visitors of a SharePoint 2010 site have to be retrieved.

I know that we could configure health and usage data collection from Central Administration which would log usage reports into log files & logging database as well.

The site for which reports have to be collected is a production site and hence it is not possible to query the log database (or) use any third party log analyzer to format the report.

Is it possible to achieve this through Object Model (Client/Server), PowerShell or through any OOTB Webparts? Any insights on this would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

*You can use Google Analytics tool . It can give you all the necessary results which you need .
http://davecoleman146.com/2011/01/31/adding-google-analytics-to-your-sharepoint-2010-site/
There is only a javascript which needs to be added in master page and all traffic is captured by Google .
OR
If you are ready to spend some money , use the WEB Trends tool . Its good and Microsoft itslef uses Web trends to track the users.*

PS:[How to get Unique visitors per page using the OOTB Web analytics in Sharepoint 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47735/how-to-get-unique-visitors-per-page-using-the-ootb-web-analytics-in-sharepoint-2/93921#93921)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the audit logs API

```
SPAuditQuery query = 
  new SPAuditQuery(SPContext.Current.Site);
SPAuditEntryCollection entries =   SPContext.Current.Site.Audit.GetEntries(query);
```

source: 
http://spuser.blogspot.be/2011/10/spaudit-how-to-read-from-audit-log.html